# Angular Material Datepicker: Change event not firing when selecting date

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm using Angular and Angular Material's Datepicker. Everything is working fine for the most part, however I added a `(change)` event that is only working when the user manually types in a date. It does not get triggered when the user clicks on a date from the datepicker popup. To be clear, the value for `date` does in fact change when the user clicks on a date, it is just the `(change)` event, and ultimately my `updateCalcs()` function that for some reason doesn't get triggered. How can I trigger an event when the user clicks on a date from the datepicker?

```
<md-input-container>
    <input mdInput [mdDatepicker]="datePicker" placeholder="Choose Date" name="date" [(ngModel)]="date" (change)="updateCalcs()" required>
    <button mdSuffix [mdDatepickerToggle]="datePicker"></button>
</md-input-container>
<md-datepicker #datePicker></md-datepicker>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `selectedChanged` inside `md-datepicker`.

`<md-datepicker #datePicker  (selectedChanged)="updateCalcs($event)"></md-datepicker>`

`$event` will emit the new value which you can use in your `updateCalcs()` function.

```
updateCalcs(event){
  console.log(event);
}
```

[Similar demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/5yhpmqSVA9dv3bX0rGEq?p=preview)

Comment: Did you mean to say md-datepicker instead of md-autocomplete? Either way, I got it to work with your change.

Answer (score 53):

There's a `dateChange` event that's raised both when the date is edited in the text box and when the date is changed via the calendar control.
See [here](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/api)

```html
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="datepicker" required placeholder="Choose a date" (dateChange)="valueChanged($event)">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="datepicker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #datepicker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: This is the only answer on the entire solution that worked for me.  Accepted answer did not.  I am using Angular  7>

Comment: Well, this doesn't seem to work if you have the action buttons enabled.

Comment: Detecting only date or only time or both date time change as well if used with ngx date time picker. So can be used with any: datepicker, timepicker or datetime picker

Answer (score 20):

Replace `change` with `ngModelChange`

Change from

```
<input mdInput 
       [mdDatepicker]="datePicker" 
       placeholder="Choose Date" 
       name="date" [(ngModel)]="date" 
       (change)="updateCalcs()" required>
```

To

```
<input mdInput 
       [mdDatepicker]="datePicker" 
       placeholder="Choose Date" 
       name="date" [(ngModel)]="date" 
       (ngModelChange)="updateCalcs()" required>
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. The accepted answer did not.

Answer (score 11):

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Input & change events"
         (dateInput)="addEvent('input', $event)" (dateChange)="addEvent('change', $event)">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

And .ts

```
addEvent(type: string, event: MatDatepickerInputEvent<Date>) {
    //console.log(event.value)
}
```

Check [here](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/examples)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer (as for version > 6.4.7)

Answer (score 2):

I must add that `(dateInput)` wasn't always firing for me, ended up using `(keyup)`

code HTML

```
  <mat-form-field>
        <input #fromInput matInput [matDatepicker]="pickerFrom" placeholder="סנן תאריך התחלה" 
          (dateChange)="filterFrom($event)" (keyup)="filterInputKeyupFrom()">
        <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="pickerFrom"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
        <mat-datepicker #pickerFrom></mat-datepicker>
    </mat-form-field>
```

final code TS

```
 private parseInputDate(v):Date{
      //this was a manual change in the input and needs to be parsed
      let a:Array<any> = v.split('.')
      a.forEach((v, i) => a[i] = parseInt(v) + (i == 1 ? -1 : 0))
      console.log(new Date(a[2], a[1], a[0]))
      return  new Date(a[2], a[1], a[0])
  }

  //(dateInput) wasn't always firing for me, ended up using (keyup)
  filterInputKeyupFrom(){
    this.lastFrom = this.parseInputDate(this.fromInput.nativeElement.value)
    if (this.lastFrom) {
      this.lastFrom.setSeconds(-1)
    }
    this.filterDates()
  }

  filterInputKeyupUpTo(){
    this.lastTo = this.parseInputDate(this.toInput.nativeElement.value)
    if (this.lastTo) {
      this.lastTo.setDate(this.lastTo.getDate()+1)
    }
    this.filterDates()
  }

  filterFrom(e:MatDatepickerInputEvent<Date>){
    console.log('filterFrom')
    //changing manually the input and then exit from it fires here
    if(e.value){
      //need to clone the date or changes are applied on the Picker
      this.lastFrom = new Date(e.value)
      if (this.lastFrom) {
        this.lastFrom.setSeconds(-1)
      }
      this.filterDates()
    }
  }

  filterUpTo(e:MatDatepickerInputEvent<Date>){
    console.log('filterUpTo')
    if(e.value){
      this.lastTo = new Date(e.value)
      if (this.lastTo) {
        this.lastTo.setDate(this.lastTo.getDate()+1)
      }
      this.filterDates()
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use ng-change to get the changed Data

```
<md-datepicker ng-change="updateCalcs()"></md-datepicker>
```

Check [Here](https://codepen.io/pen/?editors=1010)